# What is meaning of 'new' keyword in c#?

Tags: c#, python-2.7

for initializing variables for string or integer in c# we write

```
    int variable = 1
    string variable1 = "hello"
```

but for arrays why we do -

```
    string[] variable3 = new string[2]
```

instead of -

```
    string[] variable3 = ["hello","world"]
```

and also what is the meaning of new keyword here??

If you can relate it anywhere with python I will be grateful as it is the only other language I know !!

Comment: [new Operator (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa0ab757.aspx)  The array is an object and so an instance must be created.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Please don't ask about simple concepts that are explained in a million other places here...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because language fundamentals are too broad a subject to be answered here.

Answer (score 2):

You need `new`, because the specs say so.

There's syntactic sugar you can use to omit it:

```
string[] variable3 = { "hello", "world" };
```

This will still be compiled to the IL instruction [`newarr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.newarr%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4.aspx) from MS.  In the case you are talking about, the new keyword is instantiating the object which in the case you are talking about is an array. Here is how C# is [defines arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). Hope that helps.